# Passing a pointer to a pointer variable from Fortran 77 to C

Tags: c, pointers, fortran77, mixed

I have to write some code that mixes Fortran 77 with C.  Suppose I have a C function with signature

```
void foo(int ** x);
```

Thus, if I were calling **foo** in C, I might have

```
int x_val = 42;
int * x_ptr = &x_val;
foo(&x_ptr);
```

Now suppose I have this in Fortran 77:

```
integer x
x = 42
```

If I pass ***x*** to ***foo***, that would be equivalent to passing "&x" to ***foo*** in C code, but that would not work.  Do I need to create a Cray pointer of ***x*** and then pass the Cray pointer to ***foo***?  Would that work?  Is there any way to do this without Cray pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: you either have to use cray pointer or write a wrapper.

Comment: I have indeed used a Cray pointer, and it seems to be working thus far.  Thanks.